# React typescript recognizes array as object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx, react-tsx

new to react and js in general so it might be a dumb question but I can't sort it out.

I have a component like so:

```
export interface TableViewContainerProps {
    header: WorthSummaryContainerProps
    content: TableViewRowProps[]
}

export const TableViewContainer = (props: TableViewContainerProps) => {
    console.log('content type is ', typeof(props.content))
    console.log('content is ', props.content)
    return (
        <div id="tableview-container">
            <div id="tableview">
                <TableViewHeader {...props.header}/>
                <TableViewContentList {...props.content} />
                <div id="tableview-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

So when I print it it's an array of objects, all good.
`TableViewContentList` gets the content as props:

```
export const TableViewContentList = (props: TableViewRowProps[]) => {
    console.log('type of TableViewContentList props is: ', typeof(props), props)
    const tableViewContents = props.map((row) => console.log('row'))

    return (
        <div id="tableview-content-list">
            {tableViewContents}
        </div>
    )
}
```

so when I print it here it's an object not an array anymore and it breaks at the `.map`. Can someone help me out please? I feel like I'm missing something minor.

Comment: you're console logging `'row'` when it should be `row`

Comment: it fails before that, that's just a placeholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)  will give you an object when you apply it on an array inside an object.

```
type TableViewRowProps  = number;
interface TableViewContainerProps {
    content: TableViewRowProps[]
}

const props = {content: [1,2,3]}

const b = {...props.content}
console.log(b) // { "0": 1, "1": 2, "2": 3 }.
```

So the `TableViewContentList` get the props: `props[0]`, `props[1]` and `props[2]`, it's wrong.

All properties passed into a component will be attached in `props`, that's why you got an object. `props` will always be an object. So you'd better pass the `content` like this:

```
<TableViewContentList {...props} />
```

Or this:

```
<TableViewContentList content={props.content} />
```

Then you can map it to row:

```
export default function TableViewContentList(props: { content: TableViewRowProps[] }) {
  const tableViewContents = props.content.map((row) => console.log('row'));

  return <div id="tableview-content-list">{tableViewContents}</div>;
}
```